# Safari - Does not have Disable local file restrictions option

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, ionic-framework, cors

I have installed Safari in Windows 8 for development purpose , I was trying to  "Disable local file restrictions" but i could not find the option in the develop menu.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
By default Safari doesn't allow access to local files. To enable this option:
First you need to enable the develop menu.
To have the develop menu of Safari provide access to a variety of web development tools. 
To display the Develop menu: 
Open Safari.
Click on the Edit > Preferences > Advanced tab.
Check "Show Develop menu in the menu bar.
```

[image]

The develop menu is now available.
[image]

Click on the Develop menu
    Select Disable Local File Restrictions.

```
    it is also worth noting safari has some odd
 behaviour with caches, so it is also to
 use the "Disable caches" option in the same menu;
 if you are editing & debugging using safari.
```

Comment: Hi Sathish Tiwari  I did everything which u mentioned but i did not find that option in Develop menu.

Comment: it is also worth noting safari has some odd
 behaviour with caches, so it is also to
 use the "Disable caches" option in the same menu;
 if you are editing & debugging using safari.

Comment: Is there any Way to enable the "Disable local file restrictions option"